# asp.net mvc and HttpContext.Current

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing

I am trying to maintain my asp.net mvc5 app's unit test-ability by avoiding any uses of HttpContext.Current and using the HttpContextBase instance provided on each Controller which is more easily mockable.

Problem is I *need* to get access to an HttpContextBase outside of the controller and not sure the best practice here. Any suggestions?

The reason I need this is that I want cache the current user's TimeZone in the HttpContext.Items collection for use outside the controller in a config class in custom automapper function which converts my domain model to a view modal.

Comment: Please elaborate why you need to do that. That might avoid running into the [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Where outside the controller?

Answer (score 0):

I use Moq created by Daniel Cazzulino - you can find it on nuget.

You can then Mock the httpContext easily in your unit tests - removes the need for you to jump through hoops in your MVC project, thus allowing you to use HttpContext.Current happily.